# How do I compute the compact cohomology of a hypersurface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology

How do I compute the compact cohomology of a hypersurface?
For example, let $f$ be a Newton polynomial of a polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $X = (f=0)$
inside $(\mathbb{C}^\*)^n$ (maybe there is some dependency on the coefficients of $f\;$?).  Can you tell me anything about $H^*_c(X)$?  Perhaps I should know better, but I don't.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you working over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$?
That is: do you want your hypersurface in 
$\mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$ or someplace else?
Your notation makes this unclear?

Comment: I've added the arxiv ag tag, if that's ok with the OP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The classic reference is Danilov-Khovanskii's "Newton polyhedra and an algorithm for calculating Hodge-Deligne numbers". There is subsequent work by Cox, Batyrev, Malvyutov, etc. but they are mainly concerned with more general toric ambient spaces; if you want a hypersurface in the torus then this original paper should have all you need.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks super-duper.  Now looking forward to understanding it all.

Comment: For other readers, here a link to the article:  http://iopscience.iop.org/0025-5726/29/2/A02/pdf/0025-5726_29_2_A02.pdf